# Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: BASIC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, server

I am new to spring boot and trying to implement Spring security.I am trying to implement Oauth security into my project from the following reference
[spring oauth2.0 security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login)

I have created following security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

private static List<String> clients = Arrays.asList("google", "facebook");
private static String CLIENT_PROPERTY_KEY
        = "spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.";

@Autowired
private Environment env;

public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests((authorizeRequests) ->
                    authorizeRequests
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/**").permitAll()
            )
            .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
return http.build();
}

@Bean
public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
    List<ClientRegistration> registrations = clients.stream()
            .map(c -> getRegistration(c))
            .filter(registration -> registration != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(registrations);
}

@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService() {

    return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(
            clientRegistrationRepository());
}


private ClientRegistration getRegistration(String client) {
    String clientId = env.getProperty(
            CLIENT_PROPERTY_KEY + client + ".client-id");

    if (clientId == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String clientSecret = env.getProperty(
            CLIENT_PROPERTY_KEY + client + ".client-secret");

    if (client.equals("google")) {
        return CommonOAuth2Provider.GOOGLE.getBuilder(client)
                .clientId(clientId).clientSecret(clientSecret).build();
    }
    if (client.equals("facebook")) {
        return CommonOAuth2Provider.FACEBOOK.getBuilder(client)
                .clientId(clientId).clientSecret(clientSecret).build();
    }
    return null;
 }
}
```

but while running the sever I am encountering this error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientService' defined in class path resource [com/concious/interviewServiceBackend/security/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.class]: 

Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService]: Factory method 'authorizedClientService' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [com/concious/interviewServiceBackend/security/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: BASIC
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:493) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService]: Factory method 'authorizedClientService' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [com/concious/interviewServiceBackend/security/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: BASIC
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 111 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [com/concious/interviewServiceBackend/security/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: BASIC
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:493) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.clientRegistrationRepository(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig.authorizedClientService(AuthorizationServerConfig.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$authorizedClientService$2(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.authorizedClientService(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 112 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: BASIC
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 133 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BASIC
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration$Builder.<init>(ClientRegistration.java:289) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.10.RELEASE.jar:5.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration$Builder.<init>(ClientRegistration.java:284) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.10.RELEASE.jar:5.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(ClientRegistration.java:267) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.10.RELEASE.jar:5.3.10.RELEASE]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.CommonOAuth2Provider.getBuilder(CommonOAuth2Provider.java:83) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.CommonOAuth2Provider$1.getBuilder(CommonOAuth2Provider.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig.getRegistration(AuthorizationServerConfig.java:83) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig.lambda$clientRegistrationRepository$1(AuthorizationServerConfig.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1006) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig.clientRegistrationRepository(AuthorizationServerConfig.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$clientRegistrationRepository$3(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at com.concious.interviewServiceBackend.security.config.AuthorizationServerConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.clientRegistrationRepository(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 134 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

application.properties contain client details

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=<your client id>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=<your client secret>

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.client-id=<your client id>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.client-secret=<your client secret>
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

This is CommonOAuthProvider

```
public enum CommonOAuth2Provider {

GOOGLE {

    @Override
    public Builder getBuilder(String registrationId) {
        ClientRegistration.Builder builder = getBuilder(registrationId,
                ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC, DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL);
        builder.scope("openid", "profile", "email");
        builder.authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth");
        builder.tokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
        builder.jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs");
        //builder.issuerUri("https://accounts.google.com");
        builder.userInfoUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo");
        builder.userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB);
        builder.clientName("Google");
        return builder;
    }

},

GITHUB {

    @Override
    public Builder getBuilder(String registrationId) {
        ClientRegistration.Builder builder = getBuilder(registrationId,
                ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC, DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL);
        builder.scope("read:user");
        builder.authorizationUri("https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize");
        builder.tokenUri("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token");
        builder.userInfoUri("https://api.github.com/user");
        builder.userNameAttributeName("id");
        builder.clientName("GitHub");
        return builder;
    }

},

FACEBOOK {

    @Override
    public Builder getBuilder(String registrationId) {
        ClientRegistration.Builder builder = getBuilder(registrationId,
                ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST, DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL);
        builder.scope("public_profile", "email");
        builder.authorizationUri("https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth");
        builder.tokenUri("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token");
        builder.userInfoUri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email");
        builder.userNameAttributeName("id");
        builder.clientName("Facebook");
        return builder;
    }

},

OKTA {
    @Override
    public Builder getBuilder(String registrationId) {
        ClientRegistration.Builder builder = getBuilder(registrationId,
                ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC, DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL);
        builder.scope("openid", "profile", "email");
        builder.userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB);
        builder.clientName("Okta");
        return builder;
    }

};

private static final String DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = "{baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}";

protected final ClientRegistration.Builder getBuilder(String registrationId, ClientAuthenticationMethod method,
        String redirectUri) {
    ClientRegistration.Builder builder = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(registrationId);
    builder.clientAuthenticationMethod(method);
    builder.authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE);
    //builder.redirectUri(redirectUri);
    builder.redirectUriTemplate(redirectUri);
    return builder;
}

/**
 * Create a new
 * {@link org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration.Builder
 * ClientRegistration.Builder} pre-configured with provider defaults.
 * @param registrationId the registration-id used with the new builder
 * @return a builder instance
 */
public abstract ClientRegistration.Builder getBuilder(String registrationId);

}
```

exception is occurred in below method

```
protected final ClientRegistration.Builder getBuilder(String registrationId, ClientAuthenticationMethod method,
        String redirectUri) {
    **ClientRegistration.Builder builder = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(registrationId);**
    builder.clientAuthenticationMethod(method);
    builder.authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE);
    //builder.redirectUri(redirectUri);
    builder.redirectUriTemplate(redirectUri);
    return builder;
}
```